# Making a widget using multiple widgets

Tags: go, fyne

I am trying to make a file choosing widget (which I need on almost every development I am tasked with). The widget is composed of a label, an entry and a button (in that order) and it all appears horizontally on the same line.
I wish to avoid (if possible) making a brand new custom widget as 100% of the functionnality already exists in the sandard fyne widgets. So my idea was to make a custom layout and place my widgets in there.
The problem is that as my constructor function is returning a fyne.Container, I do not have access to the Entry.Text field which I need access to.
I could of course do `container.Objects[1].(widgets.Entry).Text` every time I need to access it but that just seems unintuitive.
So then I thought that I would extend the fyne.Container to return the Text to me through a method however it seems container doesn't have something similar to `ExtendBaseWidget()` to get all the functionnality of a container.
Here is the working code I have so far:

```
package fyne_custom

import (
    "os"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
    "github.com/sqweek/dialog"
)

type FileChoiceLayout struct {
    Label, Entry, Button fyne.CanvasObject
}

func (f FileChoiceLayout) MinSize(_ []fyne.CanvasObject) fyne.Size {
    total := fyne.NewSize(0, 0)
    total = total.Add(f.Label.MinSize())
    total = total.Add(f.Entry.MinSize())
    total = total.Add(f.Button.MinSize())
    return total
}

func (f FileChoiceLayout) Layout(items []fyne.CanvasObject, size fyne.Size) {
    topLeft := fyne.NewPos(0, 0)
    for _, item := range items {
        if item == f.Label {
            item.Move(topLeft)
            item.Resize(item.MinSize())
            topLeft = topLeft.Add(fyne.NewPos(item.MinSize().Width, 0))
        } else if item == f.Entry {
            item.Move(topLeft)
            width := size.Width - f.Label.MinSize().Width - f.Button.MinSize().Width
            item.Resize(fyne.NewSize(width, item.MinSize().Height))
            topLeft = topLeft.Add(fyne.NewPos(width, 0))
        } else if item == f.Button {
            item.Move(topLeft)
            item.Resize(item.MinSize())
        }
    }
}

func NewFileChoice(labelText, placeHolder, buttonText string) (*fyne.Container, *widget.Entry) {
    label := widget.NewLabel(labelText)
    entry := widget.NewEntry()
    entry.PlaceHolder = placeHolder
    button := widget.NewButton(buttonText, func() {
        cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
        file, err := dialog.File().Load()
        if err != nil {
            file = ""
        }
        if file != "" {
            entry.SetText(file)
        }
        os.Chdir(cwd)
    })
    container := container.New(&FileChoiceLayout{Label: label, Entry: entry, Button: button}, label, entry, button)
    return container, entry
}
```

The temporary workaround I found so far is to return not only the container but also the entry widget to access its Text Field.
I'm thinking there must be a better way to do it but I can't seem to find it.
Any idea would be very much appreciated!

Comment: if the purpose is to have access to the entry at the caller level, you could pass an entry object to `NewFileChoice` instead of the placeholder, no?

Comment: That would be pretty much the same thing as what I am doing now which is creating the entry widget inside the NewFileChoice function and returning it with the container. I was hoping to make the entire "widget" autonomous aka return only the container and have a container.Text() method on it. Or something similar anyway. The best scenario would be to be able to extend the container I guess. That way I have a new "widget" without having the reinvent the wheel ;) Mind you I have no idea if what I am asking is remotely possible!

Comment: Containers cannot be extended, only Widgets support this. Either keeping a reference as suggested by @blackgreen, or using the `Objects[1]` as suggested in the question are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making the custom widget.
It wasn't that much more code in the end and it works as I intended it. The only thing is that I'm not sure I did it correctly. My Destroy() and Update() methods are empty. I'm not sure if that's how it should be. And I had to use a bind string to get the data to sync between the widget struct and its renderer.
If anyone who knows better has an opinion, I am entirely open to it!
In any case, here is the code if anyone needs this widget:

```
package fyne_custom

import (
    "os"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/data/binding"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
    "github.com/sqweek/dialog"
)

type FileChoice struct {
    widget.BaseWidget
    path                               binding.String
    labelText, placeHolder, buttonText string
}

func (fc FileChoice) Text() string {
    text, _ := fc.path.Get()
    return text
}

func NewFileChoice(labelText, placeHolder, buttonText string) *FileChoice {
    f := &FileChoice{}
    f.path = binding.NewString()
    f.labelText = labelText
    f.placeHolder = placeHolder
    f.buttonText = buttonText
    f.ExtendBaseWidget(f)
    return f
}

type fileChoiceRender struct {
    fc     *FileChoice
    label  *widget.Label
    entry  *widget.Entry
    button *widget.Button
}

func (fcr fileChoiceRender) Objects() []fyne.CanvasObject {
    return []fyne.CanvasObject{fcr.label, fcr.entry, fcr.button}
}

func (fcr fileChoiceRender) MinSize() fyne.Size {
    var minHeight float32
    var totalWidth float32
    for _, item := range fcr.Objects() {
        if item.MinSize().Height > minHeight {
            minHeight = item.MinSize().Height
        }
        totalWidth += item.MinSize().Width
    }
    return fyne.NewSize(totalWidth, minHeight)
}

func (fcr fileChoiceRender) Layout(size fyne.Size) {
    topLeft := fyne.NewPos(0, 0)
    fcr.label.Move(topLeft)
    fcr.label.Resize(fyne.NewSize(fcr.label.MinSize().Width, size.Height))
    topLeft = topLeft.Add(fyne.NewPos(fcr.label.MinSize().Width, 0))
    fcr.entry.Move(topLeft)
    fcr.entry.Resize(fyne.NewSize(size.Width-fcr.label.MinSize().Width-fcr.button.MinSize().Width, size.Height))
    topLeft = topLeft.Add(fyne.NewPos(size.Width-fcr.label.MinSize().Width-fcr.button.MinSize().Width, 0))
    fcr.button.Move(topLeft)
    fcr.button.Resize(fyne.NewSize(fcr.button.MinSize().Width, size.Height))
}

func (fcr fileChoiceRender) Destroy() {}

func (fcr fileChoiceRender) Refresh() {}

func (fc FileChoice) CreateRenderer() fyne.WidgetRenderer {
    label := widget.NewLabel(fc.labelText)
    entry := widget.NewEntryWithData(fc.path)
    entry.PlaceHolder = fc.placeHolder
    button := widget.NewButton(fc.buttonText, func() {
        cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
        defer os.Chdir(cwd)
        file, err := dialog.File().Load()
        if err != nil {
            file = ""
        }
        if file != "" {
            entry.SetText(file)
        }
    })
    return &fileChoiceRender{label: label, entry: entry, button: button}
}
```

Comment: An empty `Destroy` is not uncommon. If you prefer not to use the string binding, that is what the `Refresh` would be useful for - it copies state from the widget into the renderer.

Comment: That is also what I thought for the Refresh method but I can't seem to get it to work. I think I'm misunderstanding when and how it is called and what it should do. Is it called when the widget.Entry value is updated? Is it called when the struct value is updated? Both? Do I need to call it manually? Any hints as to how I can remove the binding while keeping the synchronous behavior? I feel like it's a shame to keep the string binding when I have a method made for this.

Comment: The `Refresh` of a `WidgetRenderer` is called when the `Widget` calls after it's inherited `BaseWidget.Refresh()` is called (due to some parent refreshing, or the widget being refreshed directly). If you change the fields of a widget you then call `Refresh` to trigger the redraw - setter methods will do this for the user.

To learn more check out some of our standard widgets like `Check` https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/blob/94cadda7adaa977878ec8a8bde224030838f1db1/widget/check.go#L61